# not getting the css right

Tags: html, css

I have the requirement as per below image
[image]

I tried to this with table, but still no success in aligning the side images.

testTable.html

```
<style>
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.left-image, .right-image{
    width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.center-image{
    width: 80%;

}

</style>

<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="left-image">
            <img src="img1.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="center-image">
            <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="right-image">
            <img src="img3.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My requirement:**

I want to have center active image, with left and right images blur. side images should look like they are behind the center image

Comment: How would you like to align them? Exactly by the side of the center image?

Comment: I want to have center active image, with left and right images blur. side images should look like they are behind the center image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this code but to make it slide through slides you need to add jQuery to code. Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6fmxo90/7/)
If you need further help with that blur to side images contact me through email faceree123@gmail.com :)

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider-btns">
     <button class="slider-btn btn-1 active"></button>
     <button class="slider-btn btn-2"></button>
     <button class="slider-btn btn-3"></button>
   </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slide-img" src="your-1st-image.src">
      <!-- This is not necessary --><p>Slide 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slide-img" src="your-2nd-image.src">
      <!-- This is not necessary --><p>Slide 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slide-img" src="your-3rd-image.src">
      <!-- This is not necessary --><p>Slide 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.slider-wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 300px; /* You can choose your own width and height */
  background: grey; /* This is not necessary */
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 300%; height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  transition: 1s;
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider-btns{
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 90%;
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider-btns > button.active{
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider-btns > .slider-btn{
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider > .slide{
  text-align: center; /* This is not necessary */
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: calc((70% / 3) - 40px); height: 100%;
  background: purple; /* This is not necessary */
}
.slider-wrapper > .slider > .slide > .slide-img{
  width: 100%; height: auto;
  display: none; /* When you use this code delete this line */
}

p{
  font-family: Arial; font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 300px;
} /* This style is not necessary */
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice example. Actually according to my requirement, images should look like they are coming in front. so left and right images should look like they are underneath the central image. Also i needed some clarification from your above code: 1) this css style "width: 300%;" is because we have 3 slides right ? 2) Also can you explain this part "width: calc((70% / 3) - 40px);".

Comment: 1) yes the width 300% is because we have 3 slides. 2) 70% because we dont want the slide width to take all 100% width. We / 3 because 70% from 300% slide would be 210% but we need the room for 3 slides so we devide that by 3. And we - 40px because we have margin 20px on each side thats 40px.

Comment: I updated the file http://jsfiddle.net/c6fmxo90/8/ go and check it out! I added the effect that the side slides are behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your query still not clear to me but I tried my best to understand and answer it.

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="left-image">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="center-image">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="right-image">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.left-image, .right-image{
    width: 33.33%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.center-image{
    width: 33.33%;

}
```

Below is the result and Fiddle

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/u97oewqy/

Comment: i have done this type of view. I want the view as described in my image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this snippet helps.

**border-collapse: collapse;** on the **.container**
set **padding: 0;** the images.

```html
<style>
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.left-image, .right-image, .center-image {
  padding: 0
}

.left-image, .right-image{
    width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.center-image{
    width: 80%;
}

</style>

<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="left-image">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="center-image">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
        <td class="right-image">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this looks good, just that i want the image height and width be same. Also the left and right images should look like they are behind the central image

Comment: Try height: auto on the img s - I cannot test it right now, sorry